# Direction of rotation of torch.rot90

Tags: python, pytorch, rotation, torch

In the documentation for torch.rot90 it is stated that

> Rotation direction is from the first towards the second axis if k > 0, and from the second towards the first for k < 0.

However say that we are rotating from axis 0 to axis 1, is axis 0 rotating to axis 1 in the clockwise or anti-clockwise direction? (since they are both 90 degree rotations as per the image below)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`axis=0` is the dimension that points downwards, while `axis=1` points to the right. Visualize the axes like this:

```
---------> axis=1
|
|
|
\/
axis=0
```

Now, k>0 means counter-clockwise direction, k<0 is clockwise.

Thus,

```
>>> x = torch.arange(6).view(3, 2)
>>> x
tensor([[0, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 5]])

>>> torch.rot90(x, 1, [0,1])
tensor([[1, 3, 5],
        [0, 2, 4]])

>>> torch.rot90(x, 1, [1,0])
tensor([[4, 2, 0],
        [5, 3, 1]])
```

The `torch.rot90()`  is similar to `numpy.rot90()`

e.g.

`numpy.rot90(m, k=3, axes=(0, 1))`

would graphically be represented as per the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To me those rotations make more sense when reasonning with heights and widths. If you consider `axis=0` as the height dimension and `axis=1` as the width dimension. Then:

Take a simple input matrix `x`:

```
>>> x
tensor([[0, 1],
        [2, 3]])
```

- `k > 0`: `axis=0` towards `axis=1`, it corresponds to "height towards width", which means anti-clockwise.

  ```
  >>> x.rot90(k=1)
  tensor([[2, 0],
          [3, 1]])
  ```
- `k < 0`: `axis=1` towards `axis=0`, this time it's "width towards height, *i.e.* clockwise rotation.

  ```
  >>> x.rot90(k=-1)
  tensor([[1, 3],
          [0, 2]])
  ```